# Drush returns error page

Tags: 6, drush

When I enter

```
drush -d -v status
```

I get

```
dev@drupal-staging:/var/www/$ drush -d -v satus
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.03 sec, 2.36 MB]                                       [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 6.22 root directory at /var/www/ [0.04 sec, 3 MB]                                           [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.05 sec, 3.06 MB]                                       [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.09 sec, 3.5 MB]                                                 [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.11 sec, 3.84 MB]                              [bootstrap]
Undefined index:  SERVER_PROTOCOL bootstrap.inc:903 [0.17 sec, 6.69 MB]                                             [notice]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /opt/drush/includes/drush.inc:820) [warning]
bootstrap.inc:903 [0.17 sec, 6.69 MB]
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="misc/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<title>Site off-line | DEV </title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="modules/system/defaults.css?0" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="modules/system/system.css?0" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="modules/system/system-menus.css?0" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="modules/system/maintenance.css?0" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="themes/garland/style.css?0" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="themes/garland/minnelli/minnelli.css?0" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="themes/garland/print.css?0" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="themes/garland/fix-ie.css />    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<!-- Layout -->
<div id="header-region" class="clear-block"></div>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container" class="clear-block">

<div id="header">
<div id="logo-floater">
<h1><a href="" title="DEV "><img src="themes/garland/minnelli/logo.png" alt="DEV " id="logo" /><span>DEV </span></a></h1>        </div>

</div> <!-- /header -->


<div id="center"><div id="squeeze"><div class="right-corner"><div class="left-corner">
<h2>Site off-line</h2>                              <div class="clear-block">
<p>The site is currently not available due to technical problems. Please try again later. Thank you for your understanding.</p><hr /><p><small>If you are the maintainer of this site, please check your database settings in the <code>settings.php</code> file and ensure that your hosting provider's database server is running. For more help, see the <a href="http://drupal.org/node/258">handbook</a>, or contact your hosting provider.</small></p><p><small>The <em>mysqli</em> error was: <em>Can&#039;t connect to local MySQL server through socket &#039;/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock&#039; (2)</em>.</small></p>          </div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div></div></div></div> <!-- /.left-corner, /.right-corner, /#squeeze, /#center -->


</div> <!-- /container -->
</div>
<!-- /layout -->

</body>
</html>
Drush command could not be completed. [0.17 sec, 6.71 MB]                                                        [error]
dev@drupal-staging:/var/www/$
```

Since drush was working on this machine, I must have broken it somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that I'm working on a multi site installation with a non working default configuration. Setting the host parameter for drush solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You are using php-cgi to run Drush.  Use php-cli.

Comment: More on this here: http://drupal.org/node/1349732#comment-5463700

Comment: valid thought dear  greg!